# how to read string part in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this string :

```
<meis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" uri="localhost/naro-nei" onded="flpSW531213" identi="lemenia" id="75" lastStop="bendi" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://localhost/xsd/postat.xsd xsd/postat.xsd">
```

How can I get `lastStop` property value in JAVA?

This regex worked when tested on http://www.myregexp.com/

But when I try it in java I don't see the matched text, here is how I tried :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class SimpleRegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sampleText = "<meis xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" uri=\"localhost/naro-nei\" onded=\"flpSW531213\" identi=\"lemenia\" id=\"75\" lastStop=\"bendi\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost/xsd/postat.xsd xsd/postat.xsd\">";
        String sampleRegex = "(?<=lastStop=[\"']?)[^\"']*";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sampleRegex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sampleText);
        if (m.find()) {
            String matchedText = m.group();
            System.out.println("matched [" + matchedText + "]");
        } else {
            System.out.println("didn’t match");
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the problem is that I use escape char in my test , but real string doesn't have escape inside. ?

**UPDATE**

Does anyone know why this doesn't work when used in java ? or how to make it work?

Comment: The problem is the second `?` (the one after the character group). Since the input seems to XML, the quotes aren't optional anyway, so removing it is not a problem and it makes the regex work.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer The input is not xml its a part of an xml file which was recorded to String.

Comment: that's enough. The fact that it was part of an XML file (and I assume it was well-formed) means that attributes **must** be quoted.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer that is indeed true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=lastStop=[\"']?)[^\"]+
```

Comment: try again without named grouping

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu how would I do that?

Comment: For `lastStop=123 id="1"`, it will capture `123 id=`, not to mention `uri="localhost/naro-nei?lastStop=4"`. I'm sure Java has better XML abilities.

Comment: One more thing its working on this website for regex but in java I get syntax error, `String regex = "(?<=lastStop=["']?)[^"']*";` , how to correct that?

Comment: @Kobi this is a string, not xml in this case parsing with xml is just an overhead

Comment: You need to escape the quotes: `String regex = "(?<=lastStop=[\"']?)[^\"']*";`

Comment: How to match expression with \"something\"?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work as you expect is because of the `*` in `[^\"']*`.  The lookbehind is matching at the position *before* the `"` in `lastStop="`, which is permitted because the quote is optional: `[\"']?`.  The next part is supposed to match zero or more non-quote characters, but because the next character *is* a quote, it matches zero characters.

If you change that `*` to a `+`, the second part will fail to match at that position, forcing the regex engine to bump ahead one more position.  The lookbehind will match the quote, and `[^\"']+` will match what follows.  However, you really shouldn't be using a lookbehind for this in the first place.  It's much easier to just match the whole sequence in the normal way and extract the part you want to keep via a capturing group:

```
String sampleRegex = "lastStop=[\"']?([^\"']*)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sampleRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(sampleText);
if (m.find()) {
    String matchedText = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("matched [" + matchedText + "]");
} else {
    System.out.println("didn’t match");
}
```

It will also make it easier to deal with the problem @Kobi mentioned.  You're trying to allow for values contained in double-quotes, single-quotes or no quotes, but your regex is too simplistic.  For one thing, a quoted value can contain whitespace, but an unquoted one can't.  To deal with all three possibilities, you'll need *two or three* capturing groups, not just one.

Comment: Your points might be valid I really don't know , but your regex doesn't work try it. I get this result `lastStop="bendi` instead of `bendi`

Comment: It works for me.  Notice that I'm calling `m.group(1)`, not `m.group()`.

Comment: what is the difference between these 2 calls?

Comment: `group()` returns the whole match, while `group(1)` returns the contents of the first capturing group.  In this case, there's only the one capturing group: `([^\"']*)`. ref: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29, http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html